# Select2 set option automatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, smarty, jquery-select2

I am building a support application, and it has some selectboxes. I am using select2 for these. The issue I am having, is that in my current construction, the selection of a corresponding lead to a project only occurs when someone clicks the lead select2 after having filled in a project at the project select2.

The goal is to make it so that when someone sets the project select2 value, the program automatically sets the select2 of the lead select box to the lead that corresponds to the project's ID.

*If I select project 1082 at the project select2, it needs to automatically set "J. Johnson" at the lead select2, without me having to first click said selectbox.*

Assistance would be appreciated as I cannot, even with the official documentation (https://select2.org/programmatic-control/add-select-clear-items) get to my envisioned resolution.

**project selection onchange function call**

```
$('.select2project').on("change", function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    searchLeadsByProjectID(value);
});
```

**searchLeadsByProjectID function**

```
        function searchLeadsByProjectID(id){
            $('.select2lead').select2({
                ajax: {
                    type: 'GET',
                    url: '/modules/support/ajaxLeadSearch2.php',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    delay: 250,
                    data: {
                        "id": id
                    },
                    processResults: function (data) {
                        return {
                            results: data,
                            more: false
                        };
                    }
                }
            });
        }
```

**ajaxLeadSearch2.php**

```
<?php
require_once('../../config.php');

$login = new Login();
if (!$login->checkLogin()) {
    echo lang($_SESSION['language'], "INSUFFICIENT_RIGHTS");
    exit();
}

$db = new Database();

$query = "
        SELECT
            LeadID AS lead_id,
            REPLACE(CONCAT_WS(' ', LeadInitials, LeadInsertion, LeadLastName), '  ', ' ') AS name,
            REPLACE(CONCAT_WS(' ', LeadStreet, LeadStreetNumber, LeadNumberAdjective), '  ', ' ') AS address,
            LeadZiPCode AS zipcode,
            LeadCity AS city
        FROM
            `LeadTBL`
        WHERE
            LeadID = :leadID
        ORDER BY
            LeadLastName
        ASC
    ";

$binds = array(
    ':leadID' => $_GET['id'],
);
$result = $db->select($query, $binds);
$json = array();

foreach ($result as $row){
    $json[] = array(
        'id' => $row['lead_id'],
        'text' => $row['name'] .' - '. $row['address'] .', '. $row['zipcode'] .' '. $row['city'] .' ('. $row['lead_id'] .')'
    );
}

echo json_encode($json);
```

Comment: Pull the ajax out of the select2, and run it stand alone. Then, with it completes, set the selected value. If you populate the the <select>, the select2 will "see" it the next time it opens

Comment: That is the issue; It must auto populate without a user first opening it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Appending a new option, welp. Resolved.**

```
        function searchLeadsByProjectID(id) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: '/modules/support/ajaxLeadSearch2.php',
                dataType: 'json',
                delay: 250,
                data: {"id": id}
            }).success(function (data) {
                var $leadSelect = $('.select2lead');
                for (var index in data) {
                    var d = data[index];
                    var newOption = new Option(d.text, d.id, true, true);
                    $leadSelect.append(newOption).trigger('change');
                }
            });
        }
```